# SwiftUI trying to remove object from a list but getting Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: is a 'let' constant

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I posted this entire view to a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/gesabo/604586accbb2dd9d2d5837d718cc24e4) because I think you need to see all of it.  The problem is that on swiping to delete I am deleting the HealthKit workout but I cannot delete the row in the list.  Line 132 is where I am trying to remove the workout from the list.  Uncommenting out, the compiler says "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'workoutMonth' is a 'let' constant" but it's a `var` and its `@State`?

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

struct MonthsWorkoutsListView: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @EnvironmentObject var trackerDataStore: TrackerDataStore
    @State var workoutMonths = [WorkoutMonth]()
    
    @State private var showingDeleteFailOrSuccessAlert = false
     @State private var deleteFailOrSuccessAlert = Alert(title: Text(""))
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if workoutMonths.count == 0 {
                Text("No workouts logged yet.  Open the Athlytic App on your Apple Watch to start and save a new workout.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            } else {
                List {
                    ForEach(workoutMonths) { workoutMonth in
                        Section(header: Text(getFormattedYearMonth(workoutMonth: workoutMonth))) {
                            ForEach(workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts) { workout in
                                NavigationButton(
                                    action: {
                                        trackerDataStore.selectedWorkout = workout //this line is needed so that the image  at the top of WorkoutDetailHeaderCard gets updated,  otherwise the view loads before the async called and you end up with the  image of the last selected workout
                                        trackerDataStore.loadDataForSelectedWorkout(selectedWorkoutToBeUpdated: workout)
                                    },
                                    destination: {
                                        WorkoutDetailView().environmentObject(trackerDataStore)
                                    },
                                    workoutRow: { WorkoutRow(trackerWorkout: workout) }
                                )
                            }
                            .onDelete { (offSets) in
                                deleteWorkout(offSets: offSets, workoutMonth: workoutMonth)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showingDeleteFailOrSuccessAlert ) {
                    deleteFailOrSuccessAlert
                    
                }
                
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Workouts"))
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            workoutMonths = buildWorkoutsIntoYearMonths(workouts: trackerDataStore.workouts)
        }
    }
    
    func buildWorkoutsIntoYearMonths(workouts: [TrackerWorkout]) -> [WorkoutMonth] {
        
        var data = [YearMonth: [TrackerWorkout]]()
        var tempWorkoutMonths = [WorkoutMonth]()
        
        for workout in workouts {
            //print("workout UUID = \(workout.uuid) for workout dated \(workout.startDate)")
            let yearMonth = YearMonth(date: workout.startDate)
            
            //Build a year  month  with an empty array of hockeyTracker workouts
            var yearMonthWorkouts = data[yearMonth, default: [TrackerWorkout]()]
            yearMonthWorkouts.append(workout)
            data[yearMonth] = yearMonthWorkouts
            
        }
        
        //Order YearMonths into newest > oldest
        let sortedDataKeys = data.keys.sorted(by: >)
        
        //Build yearMonths into Struct which is needed for SwiftUI
        for yearMonth in sortedDataKeys  {
            let newYearMonth = WorkoutMonth(yearMonth: yearMonth, trackerWorkouts: data[yearMonth]!)
            tempWorkoutMonths.append(newYearMonth)
        }
        return tempWorkoutMonths
    }
    
    
    func getFormattedYearMonth(workoutMonth: WorkoutMonth) -> String {
        
        var monthAsString = ""
        
        switch (workoutMonth.yearMonth.month) {
        case 1: monthAsString = "January"
        case 2: monthAsString = "February"
        case 3: monthAsString = "March"
        case 4: monthAsString = "April"
        case 5: monthAsString = "May"
        case 6: monthAsString = "June"
        case 7: monthAsString = "July"
        case 8: monthAsString = "August"
        case 9: monthAsString = "September"
        case 10: monthAsString = "October"
        case 11: monthAsString = "November"
        case 12: monthAsString = "December"
            
        default:
            print("Default")
        }
        
        let yearAsString = (workoutMonth.yearMonth.year.description)
        let yearWithoutFirst2Char = yearAsString.dropFirst(2)
        
        let formattedSection = "\(monthAsString) '\(yearWithoutFirst2Char)"
        
        return formattedSection
    }
    
    private func deleteWorkout(offSets: IndexSet, workoutMonth: WorkoutMonth) {
        
        for offset in offSets {
            if let unwrappedHKWorkout = workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts[offset].hkWorkout {
                
                guard unwrappedHKWorkout.sourceRevision.source.name == "Athlytic" else {
                    print("sourceName isn't Athlytic it is \(unwrappedHKWorkout.sourceRevision.source.name)")
                    showingDeleteFailOrSuccessAlert.toggle()
                    deleteFailOrSuccessAlert = Alert(title: Text("Delete Error"), message: Text("Apple only permits us to delete a workout that was logged with the Athlytic Watch App.  To delete this workout you need to delete it in the Apple Health or Fitness App."), dismissButton: .default(Text("ok")))
                    return
                    
                }
                
                HKHealthStore().delete(unwrappedHKWorkout) { (success, error) in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if success {
                            print("success workout deleted")
                           //workoutMonth.trackerWorkouts.remove(at: offset)
                            showingDeleteFailOrSuccessAlert.toggle()
                            deleteFailOrSuccessAlert = Alert(title: Text("workout successfully deleted"))
                            
                        } else if let unwrappedError = error {
                            print("error could not delete workout because \(unwrappedError)")
                            showingDeleteFailOrSuccessAlert.toggle()
                            deleteFailOrSuccessAlert = Alert(title: Text("Delete Error"), message: Text("We were unable to delete this workout due to \(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("ok")))
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

//struct MonthsWorkoutsList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
//    static var previews: some View {
//        MonthsWorkoutsListView()
//    }
//}



struct YearMonth: Comparable, Hashable {
    
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    
    init(year: Int, month: Int) {
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
    }
    
    init(date: Date) {
        let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: date)
        self.year = comps.year!
        self.month = comps.month!
    }
    
    static func < (lhs: YearMonth, rhs: YearMonth) -> Bool {
        if lhs.year != rhs.year {
            return lhs.year < rhs.year
        } else {
            return lhs.month < rhs.month
        }
    }
}

struct WorkoutMonth: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var yearMonth: YearMonth
    var trackerWorkouts: [TrackerWorkout]
}
```

Comment: Please don’t post links to your code. I have updated your question to include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to modify `workoutMonth`, which is a parameter coming into the function, making it a `let` variable by default.

You'll need to do something more like this (*Note that this is untested and possibly imprecise since you didn't give a simple project to play with and I'm just reading from the gist, but it should at least get you started*):

```
self.workoutMonths = self.workoutMonths.map { wm in 
  if wm.id == workoutMonth.id {
   var copiedMonth = wm
   copiedMonth.trackerWorkouts.remove(at: offset)
   return copiedMonth
  } else {
   return wm
  }
}
```